# Selecting a single field in a fetch into an array to load a picker

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5, nsfetchrequest

trying to load a single field into an array and then loading that in a picker.  I think its in the creation of the array that I have a problem.

This is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescr];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
self.pickerData = array;
```

The error I get is this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bb8100'

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: seems like issue in picker delegate, there you might comparing wrong objects, can u post some code of picker delegate as well.

Comment: all I do after the last line you see is

Comment: [vPicker reloadAllComponents];  I made sure it was working without the data from a table by  NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"data", @"data 1", @"data 2",nil]; then commented this part out

Comment: is that works after commenting that?

Comment: the part with fake array being created with @"data" etc.. works.... so I figure I can narrow this down to just loading the single field from a fetch into an array and leave the rest alone but ...

Comment: when I used the NSArray with the specified objects @"data", @"data 1" etc... I put a checked the value of array and I got 

(gdb) print-object array1
<__NSArrayI 0x7b7d9f0>(
data,
data 1,
data 2
)

however when I use the fetch the value of the array looks like...
<_PFArray 0x7beb9d0>(
<NSManagedObject: 0x7beb6d0> (entity: Names; id: 0x7beacd0 <x-coredata://11E70D04-B41F-4C95-BCED-2D597BF26A8C/Names/p2> ; data: <fault>)
)

Comment: The main issue is might be with the comparison logic that you are having, you are comparing element suspecting string while you are receiving NSManaged object, that causes this crash.

Comment: how do i change the fetch to result in an array of strings then?

Comment: Check out answer, also if you post what is in your nsmanaged object and what you want to fetch from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the documentation of NSManaged Object-
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html

Then fetch the data properly and pass to Picker.
Main issue is wrong kind of comparison of objects, due to which app is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're assuming the objects in your `pickerData` array are `NSString` instances, when in fact they are `NSManagedObject` instances. In order to get the value of the name field, you should do the following:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *name = [managedObject valueForKey:@"name"];

    return name;
}
```